# Is calling methods in parent class a bad idea?

Tags: php, oop

In real world project, we had a pretty long PHP class, and during refactoring it was broken into 2 smaller classes, ClassA and ClassB, where ClassA extends ClassB (just an example names). There were some issues with legacy code, so we had to do that way.

In ClassB we call some methods from ClassA (they're not overriden, I mean, methods doesn't exists in ClassB). Is that a bad idea in OOP?

Edit: obviosly, in the rest of code we always initiate only ClassA. But wondering is calling parent class from the child a big "NO" in OOP terms?

Comment: _"Is that a bad idea in OOP?"_ No, that's the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: Wait, does A extend B or does B extend A? Your explanation seems to conflict itself.

Comment: `classB` should be an abstract class, so that you can't instantiate it by itself. Otherwise, you'll try to call methods from the child class that don't exist.

Comment: @AlexHowansky ClassA extends ClassB, as I wrote. ClassA contains method Method1(), and in ClassB we have some method that calls Method1() (which is in parent class).
ClassA extends ClassB {

Comment: @AlexHowansky Example code (sorry, can't format it):

    class ClassA extends ClassB {
        public function someMethod() {
            /* some code */
        }
    }

    class ClassB {
        public function run() {
            $this->someMethod();
        }
    }

Comment: This won't work, your design is inverted. ClassB has no method called `someMethod()` available to it. The parent should never assume that certain methods exist in the child. The parent shouldn't really even know that children exist. It should define all the methods that are common to all children. Then the children extend the parent and override parent methods and/or add additional child-specific methods. E.g., given `class Parent { function foo() { ... } }` and `class Child { function bar() { ... } }` , Parent has only `foo()` available to it, while Child has both `foo()` and `bar()`.

Answer (score -1):

What you're describing is a common pattern in OOP. The parent class should be an abstract class, so it can't be instantiated by itself, only the child classes can be instantiated.

The child classes are all required to implement methods that aren't in the parent class, but some methods are common to all the classes, and they're implemented in the parent. These common methods then defer to the children for some implementation aspects that are child-specific.